# Subfloor or partition walls first in a cottage attic?

Tags: floor, attic, frame, timber-framing

Its time for me to think about the internals of an attic in a traditional British one and a half storey cottage.

Picture of 1st floor inside cottage

[image]

*Note this is just spare bits of timber sarking as a temporary floor. The floor will be 22mm T&G chipboard.*

Looking at various videos online I am not sure what is the best / correct way to go about it.

So, do I put my chipboard flooring on first, then the studwork frames?

Is it ok for the studwork partitions to be screwed onto the chipboard flooring, or do they need to be directly fixed to the joists?

Here is a diagram of my thinking, two ways

[image]

Any other suggestions or advice welcome!

Comment: Please limit your questions to 1 question at a time. Without some editing, this feels like it's too broad and needs some focus. For Q1 - how would you propose holding up the flooring while you're assembling the framing below it, if you were to attempt this method? I've never heard of anyone trying to put down flooring _before_ installing the framing to hold it up?

Comment: @FreeMan updated my question to be a bit more clear. Essentially do I build studword partitions onto the joists directly or can I lay the chipboard floor first, then fix the partitions onto the chipboard.

Comment: Is "chipboard" OSB? Industry terms are most clear.

Comment: Its called Caberfloor, its definitely not OSB. Not sure what the equivalent in USA is.
https://www.norbord.co.uk/our-products/caberfloor/caberfloor-p5/

Comment: Interesting, that Caberfloor is what I'd call T&G OSB with a particle board surface. At 22mm (about 7/8") it seems to be reasonably thick, and if it's water resistant, then I guess all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to put in your floor joists, lay down the sub floor, then build partition walls on top of that.

It's unlikely that all your partition walls will fall exactly on a joist, so without subflooring you'll be going through all sorts of gymnastics to support the wall.  Since none of your partition walls will be load bearing, you won't have to worry about walls bearing on joists - just use standard dimensional lumber with stud spacing to match your national standards.

Also, I believe that "chipboard" means different things in different parts of the world. So long as the stuff you're using is rated for flooring use, you should be fine. (Here in the States, what I think of when I hear "chipboard" would *not* be suitable for flooring.)

Comment: Thanks, my joists are already installed. 

I am using a product called Caberfloor, its a type of chipboard in the UK but very strong 22mm thick and water resistent - https://www.norbord.co.uk/our-products/caberfloor/caberfloor-p5/